# changing ngModel only triggers writeValue once

Tags: angular, primeng, ngmodel

I have a custom component which gets an object bound with `ngModel`.

Inside the component I read a numeric value of the object and display it in a `primeng number input`.

The problem is that the `primeng number input`'s `(ngModelChange)` event only triggered when the input loses focus.

In our application this is a problem since we normally use `keyup.enter` to jump to a different input. When using `keyup.enter` the input hasn´t lost focus and thus the `ngModel` did not change.

I've build a method for the component which makes the input lose focus first. This works great in changing the `ngModel`. We then set the `ngModel` to `null` to clear the input but this only works the first time.

On the second time the value just stays inside the input.

I reproduced the problem in this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-inputnumber-demo-yn454v?)

Comment: From what I see in your StackBlitz the input gets cleared every time, I can't reproduce

Comment: So you are entering a number and press enter it gets cleared and when entering another number and pressing enter it gets also cleared?

Comment: Yes 100% https://gyazo.com/f6d436da95726aa1eadcc00b996684c5

Answer (score 0):

Can you assign a new object with value 0 instead of null ?

```
changeValue() {
    console.log(this.value)
    this.value = {value: 0};
}
```

This will surely make the ngModel detect a change and trigger the writeValue() method inside your component. I think the problem is assigning 2 times the `null` value it doesn't detect any difference.

Comment: assigning value 0 sadly is not an option since the input should be empty and not display 0. In our case the input displays different units like mg, ml etc and 0 would mean something different. I dont think the problem is that i assign null two times because `this.value` is clearly not null before changing it to null.

Comment: So assign { value: null }
I know that `this.value` is not null the first time, and that is why it's works the first time and the change is detected. I think is the second time when the problem occurs, when you assign it again to null.

Answer (score 0):

In primeng you has the event (onInput), see [the docs](https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/inputnumber), the part of "events". So you can do

```
<p-inputNumber ....(onInput)="change($event)"></p-inputNumber>

change(event)
{
   //see that event is an object with two properties:
   //originalEvent: Browser event
   //value: new Value
   this._onChange({value: event.value})
}
```

**Updated** if in version 9 you has not event onInput, you can try -I don't check- using event keyup passing the own p-number. For this use a template reference variable

```
<p-inputNumber #myinput (keyup)="change(myinput)" ... >
change(pInput)
{
  console.log(pInput.input.nativeElement.value)
}
```

Comment: We are using prime ng 9 and there onInput is not available. We could not upgrade since our template was not updated to primeng 10

Comment: I has no idea about prime ng 9, you can try use a template reference variable and pass to the document keyup, in primeng 10 you can access to the value using `event.input.nativeElement.value`. I updated the answer, but I can not check because I has not primer ng. You can use console.log(pInput) and see if you can get the value of the input